# jQuery sort by rating (desc) and hide divs based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

I am trying to achieve the following. I have a dozen divs with something like:

```
    <div id=1><div>test 1</div><div>4</div></div>
<div id=2><div>test2</div><div>1</div></div>
<div id=3><div>test3</div><div>6</div></div>
<div id=4><div>test4</div><div>3</div></div>
<div id=5><div>test5</div><div>2</div></div>
<div id=6><div>test6</div><div>0</div></div>
<div id=7><div>test7</div><div>3</div></div>
 ...
```

Now I want to use jQuery to display only the top 5 divs i.e. the ones with rating 4,6,3,2,3 **in that order** and hide the rest.

Any idea how to go about this? I would prefer not to use any extra plugins etc.

Comment: do you just want to show the top 5 no matter what their content? Or do you want to display the top 5 _based_ on their content?

Comment: they will have different content ofcourse. but depending on the ratings, i want to hide all divs which are not the top 5. please note top 5 does not mean first 5.

Comment: And they won't be sorted in any way? Like you're showing them now: 4, 2, 6, 4, 1, 1, 0. If there was an eight div with content of 7, then that div needs to be showed as well? Makes sense?

Comment: yes right... sorry if my questions wasnt too clear.

Comment: it should bascially hide the remaining which are not the top 5 rated ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give your HTML more structure, so that you can use it with selectors:

```
<div class="song">
    <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="song">
    <div>2</div>
</div>
<div class="song">
    <div>6</div>
</div>
<div class="song">
    <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="song">
    <div>1</div>
</div>
<div class="song">
    <div>1</div>
</div>
<div class="song">
    <div>0</div>
</div>
```

### `O(n*logn)`

```
allSongs = $("div.song").get();
allSongs.sort(function(a,b) {
    a = $(a);
    b = $(b);
    // calling a.text() does only work if there's no text besides the rating.
    if (a.text() > b.text()) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a.text() < b.text()) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});

// hide all elements that have an index greater/equal to 5
$(allSongs.slice(5)).hide();
```

### `O(n*m)`

```
songs = $("div.song").get();
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var indexOfTop = -1;
    var topRating = -1;
    // find best rated song
    jQuery.each(songs, function(j) {
        // this line needs to be adapted for your code
        var rating = $(this).text();
        if (rating > topRating) {
            topRating = rating;
            indexOfTop = j;
        }
    }); 
    // remove top item from array
    if (indexOfTop == -1) {
        // no items left in songs
        return false;
    } else {
        songs.splice(indexOfTop, 1);
    }
}

// remove remaining songs
$(songs).hide();
```

### `O(m*logn)`

```
function BinaryHeap(keyFunction) { 
    if (arguments.length >= 1) { 
        this.keyFunction = keyFunction; 
    } 
    this.content = []; 
} 

BinaryHeap.buildHeap = function(items, keyFunction) { 
    var newHeap = new BinaryHeap(); 
    if (arguments.length >= 2) { 
        this.keyFunction = keyFunction; 
    } 
    // slice copies the array 
    newHeap.content = items.slice(0); 
    var firstParent = Math.floor((newHeap.content.length - 1) / 2); 
    for (var i = firstParent; i >= 0; i--) { 
        newHeap._siftDown(i); 
    } 
    return newHeap; 
} 

BinaryHeap.prototype = { 
    push: function(item) { 
        this.content.push(item) 
        this._siftUp(this.content.length - 1); 
    }, 
    pop: function() { 
        var value = this.content[0]; 
        var newHead = this.content.pop(); 
        if (this.content.length >= 1) { 
            this.content[0] = newHead; 
            this._siftDown(0); 
        } 

        return value; 
    }, 
    // default key function, it extracts a key from the object 
    keyFunction: function(a) { 
        return a; 
    }, 
    _siftDown: function(root) { 
        var length = this.content.length; 
        var k = 0; 
        while (root * 2 + 1 < length) { 
            k++; 
            var child = root * 2 + 1; 
            var rightChild = root * 2 + 2; 
            if (rightChild < length) { 
                child = this._max(child, rightChild); 
            } 

            if (this._max(root, child) == child) { 
                this._swap(root, child); 
            } else { 
                break; 
            } 
            root = child; 
        } 
    }, 
    _siftUp: function(child) { 
        while (child >= 0) { 
            var root = Math.floor((child - 1) / 2); 
            if (this._max(child, root) == root) { 
                this._swap(child, root); 
            } else { 
                return; 
            } 
            child = root; 
        } 
    }, 
    _max: function(a, b) { 
        return (this.keyFunction(this.content[a]) >= this.keyFunction(this.content[b])) ? a : b; 
    }, 
    _swap: function(a, b) { 
        var buffer = this.content[a]; 
        this.content[a] = this.content[b]; 
        this.content[b] = buffer; 
    } 
} 

allSongs = $("div.song"); 
// build heap in O(n) 
var myheap = BinaryHeap.buildHeap(allSongs.get(), function(item) { 
    return $(item).text(); 
}); 

// hide all items 
allSongs.hide(); 

// show top 5 
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    var item = myheap.pop(); 
    // less than 5 elements 
    if (typeof(item) == "undefined") 
        break; 
    $(item).show(); 
}
```

### `O(n)`

Quite sure it's not possible.

### [Timed results](http://jsbin.com/aduho)

```
Results in Milliseconds
(Mac OS X 10.6, Safari 4.0.3, 2.4 Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo)
-------
10 elements
n*logn: 3
m*n: 2
m*logn: 2

100 elements
n*logn: 26
m*n: 11
m*logn: 5

1000 elements
n*logn: 505
m*n: 140
m*logn: 42

10000 elements
n*logn: 8016
m*n: 1648
m*logn: 442
```

Comment: adapted it as per my requirements. works pretty much like a charm. will let you know incase i have any problems... thanks a ton... anything more efficient than this?

Comment: sorry... done.... will mostly accept this as answer... wondering if this can be done more efficiently?

Comment: I've just added a O(n*m) method, but please be aware that for small datasets the built-in `sort()` method is probably still faster.

Comment: Using a heap you could create a solution which is `O(m*logn)` which is the best runtime you can get.

Comment: I love this answer, tis truly awesome. I wish I could vote it up more.

Comment: extremely comprehensive. thank you very much. i always thought heap sort was only meant for academic purposes :)

Comment: You could improve the performance even more if you cached the key extracted for the heap. But the first method is probably still the fastest because of its use of the built-in sort() function.

Comment: @ Alec Smart: Priority Queues are another example of heaps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick hack I made up, so if it result's in death, I'm not liable...

```
var divs = $('div[id] div:contains("test") + div').get();

divs = divs.sort(function( a, b ) {
  return ( parseInt( b.textContent, 10 ) || -1 ) - ( parseInt( a.textContent, 10 ) || -1 );
}).slice(5);

$( divs ).hide();
```

But I agree that more HTML structure definitely makes your job easier...